# Angular validator, pass data along with error code to be displayed in ngMessages

Tags: angularjs, data-binding, error-code, named-ranges, angularjs-validation

Is that possible to store some additional data along with the error flag itself, using standard Angular mechanism? 
i.e. I'm manually setting `ngModel.$setValidity`, I'd like to pass some data along with the error flag, to be displayed in `ngMessages` directive.
For example let's assume the min/max length of the field depends upon some external factors, thus is computed & validated server-side. The server respons with `customlength` error code along with `max` and `min` properties, which I'd like to display to the user.
Currently I'm simply setting `ngModel.$setValidity("customlength", false);` but I'd like to pass `{max: response.max, min: response.min}` along, to be interpolated in the template like `<div ng-message="customlength">the length should be between {{ data.min }} and {{ data.max }}`

Comment: Can't you just put your `data` object in the scope once you receive it?

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to pass {max: response.max, min: response.min} along, to be interpolated in the template like the length should be between {{ data.min }} and {{ data.max }}

Use the root scope to store the value(s) intended to be output within the message string:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-messages.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('ngMessagesExample',['ngMessages']);
</script>
  
<body ng-app="ngMessagesExample">
  <form name="myForm" id="{{$root.$id}}">
  <label>
    <p>Enter Min:<input type="text" ng-model="form_min">
    <p>Enter Max:<input type="text" ng-model="form_max">
    <p>Enter your name:
    <input type="text"
           name="myName"
           ng-model="name"
           ng-minlength="form_min"
           ng-maxlength="form_max"
           required />
  </label>
   <p>
   <input type="radio" required name="foo" ng-model="foo" value="1">Yes
   <input type="radio" required name="foo" ng-model="foo" value="2">No
   </p>
   <p>
   Foo: <input type="text" ng-model="myForm.foo.$modelValue">
   </p>
   <p>
   <input type="submit" value="{{myForm.foo.$error.required ? 'No' : 'Yes'}}">
   </p>
  <pre>myForm.myName.$error = {{ myForm.myName.$error | json }}</pre>

  <div ng-messages="myForm.foo.$error"   style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Pick one</div>
  </div>
  
  <div ng-messages="myForm.myName.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
    <div ng-message="required">Your value should be between {{form_min}} and {{form_max}} characters long</div>
    <div ng-message="minlength" id="{{$id}}">Your value is less than {{form_min}}</div>
    <div ng-message="maxlength" id="{{$id}}">Your value is greater than  {{form_max}}</div>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
```

**References**

- [Easy Form Validation in AngularJS with ngMessages — SitePoint](https://www.sitepoint.com/easy-form-validation-angularjs-ngmessages/)
- [AngularJS: Developer Guide: Migrating from Previous Versions](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/migration)
- [Explicitly providing ng-model to DOM elements | TO THE NEW Blog](http://www.tothenew.com/blog/explicitly-providing-ng-model-to-dom-elements/)
- [Using NgModelController with Custom Directives](https://www.nadeau.tv/using-ngmodelcontroller-with-custom-directives/)